# picketlink , saml2login module , signed metadata - How this combination really works without any code?

Tags: jboss, saml-2.0, signed, picketlink

After stuck up for a week to understand this combination in the context of setting up an SP in JBOSS EAP 6 in an IdP initiated SAML with post binding , I still have no idea how just by configurations the saml2loginmodule and signed metadata and response process works.

1]Standalone.xml -> Authentication module is specified as org.picketlink.identity.federation.bindings.jboss.auth.SAML2LoginModule

2]In picketlink.xml org.picketlink.identity.federation.core.impl.KeyStoreKeyManager  and FederationHandlers are defined in order

3]domain is already created in JBOSS.

What I am trying to understand is , when the SAML response hits the url https://mySPsite/context-givenin-jbossweb-xml/ 
what happens to the token received by this url ? It reaches the SAML2logonModule without any specific coding from the developer side ? Is this sufficient to have an SP to support digitally signed response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I could figure out the flow. The request is intercepted by the Authenticator Module - SAML2Module here - and after validating the assertions , it sets the user's security context. From there application can inherit this module and get the data set in the security context.